# Best way to define an object with a list

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming

The idea is to define objects like circles, or triangles with a list. I made this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newList}{m}
 {\seq_new:c { l_am_list_#1_seq }}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addToList}{mm}
 {\seq_put_right:cn { l_am_list_#1_seq } { #2 }}
\NewDocumentCommand{\getFromList}{mm}
 {\seq_item:cn { l_am_list_#1_seq } { #2 }}
 \NewDocumentCommand{\drawcircle}{m}
 {\node [draw] at (\getFromList{#1}{1}) [circle~through={(\getFromList{#1}{2})}] {};}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newList{C_1}
\addToList{C_1}{A}
\addToList{C_1}{B}
\newList{C_2}
\addToList{C_2}{B}
\addToList{C_2}{C}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (C) at (0,-3);
  \drawcircle{C_1}
  \drawcircle{C_2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps my idea is a bad idea. Is a list the right tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `\getFromList` this way, it has to be *expandable*. Depending on the implementation, this may or may not be possible. In your case, it is possible because your `\getFromList` only uses `\seq_item:Nn` and an implicit `\csname ... \endcsname`,<sup>1</sup> which is expandable. `\seq_item:Nn` is itself expandable because of the star in its documentation (see *Documentation conventions* in [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), page 4 in the version from 2020-04-06):

[image]

Thus, you only need to declare your `\getFromList` command using `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` (`\NewDocumentCommand` would make it a `\protected` macro; as a consequence, it wouldn't expand inside `\edef` and friends).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newList}{m}
  {
    \seq_new:c { l_am_list_#1_seq }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addToList}{mm}
 {
   \seq_put_right:cn { l_am_list_#1_seq } {#2}
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getFromList}{mm}
  {
    \seq_item:cn { l_am_list_#1_seq } {#2}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawcircle}{m}
 {
   \node [draw] at (\getFromList{#1}{1})
     [circle~through={(\getFromList{#1}{2})}] {};
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newList{C_1}
\addToList{C_1}{A}
\addToList{C_1}{B}
\newList{C_2}
\addToList{C_2}{B}
\addToList{C_2}{C}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (C) at (0,-3);
  \drawcircle{C_1}
  \drawcircle{C_2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Footnote**

1. Because of the `c` argument type.